# Zend framework 2 cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel, zend-framework-2

Acabei de fazer um curso de zend framework 2 e tenho um projeto pronto, todas as pastas estão dentro do "skeleton-application", porém quando fui subir tudo na pasta public da o seguinte erro :

> *Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>   Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@systemgator.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>   More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>   Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*

gostaria de saber se precisa alterar alguma coisa e onde alterar, pois em minha máquina local funciona.